# Moving a database to another server for MVC C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to move a database from the local server to another. So I moved all the data through SSMS tool to another database. In the application I have now 2 connection strings and tried to exchange them but do not know how to do it well.

local db connection string:

```
 connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BiuroModel.csdl|res://*/Models.BiuroModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.BiuroModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=KOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DefaultConnection;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

my second server connection string:

```
Data Source=db-mssql;Initial Catalog=inzS9776;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=inzS9776;Password=xxxxxxx
```

My local connection string was auto generated by ADO.NET but when I try exchange these connections string I get some errors like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework connection strings wrap a normal SQL Server connection string, just replace the appropriate part, observe:

```
metadata=res://*/Models.BiuroModel.csdl|res://*/Models.BiuroModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.BiuroModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=
    &quot;
        data source=KOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS;
        initial catalog=DefaultConnection;
        integrated security=True;
        MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
        App=EntityFramework
    &quot;
```

Replace the bit after `provider connection string=` with the new SQL Server connection string, and don't forget to wrap it in `&quot;`.

Comment: Ok it works! But could you tell me why when I create a new user is added to the local database and not to the database on an external server? Both databases have the same tables. On the other hand, when I create any data other than creating a new user, they are added correctly to the external database.

Comment: @JustBeginner Your application was connected to the old server for some reason. That generally shouldn't happen. We would need to know more about your application before saying anything, but I don't think it will happen again.